# AJAX not loading -- at wit's end

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

Okay, to anyone who's been tracking this question: I thank you for your patience and help.  I am completely redoing the question to hopefully facilitate answers, insights, or even just a theory.  To present my XML code, I reduced it to only the elements needed to reproduce the problem.

As I explained in my original post, the XML file is meant to store data on academic courses, in a semester>course>unit>text hierarchy.  Here is a minimal example:

```
 <MLIS>
    <semester>
        <semesterInfo>
            <semNumber>1</semNumber>
            <season>Spring</season>
            <semYear>2014</semYear>
        </semesterInfo>
        <courses>
            <course>
                <courseInfo>
                    <department>IRLS</department>
                    <courseNumber>504</courseNumber>
                    <courseTitleInfo>
                        <courseTitle>Foundations</courseTitle>
                    </courseTitleInfo>
                </courseInfo>
                <units>
                    <unit>
                        <unitInfo>
                            <unitNumber>1</unitNumber>
                            <unitTitle>Introductions</unitTitle>
                        </unitInfo>
                        <unitMaterial>
                            <resource>
                                <type>video lecture</type>
                                <titleInfo>
                                    <title>Pre-course lecture</title>
                                </titleInfo>
                                <authorInfo>
                                    <author>
                                         <firstName>Joe</firstName>
                                         <lastName>Blow</lastName>
                                         <displayForm>Blow</displayForm>
                                    </author>
                                </authorInfo>
                                <dateInfo>
                                    <dateIssued>Aug 13, 2013</dateIssued>
                                </dateInfo>
                                <extent>
                                    <time>
                                       <minutes>14</minutes>
                                       <seconds>17</seconds>
                                    </time>
                                </extent>
                                <competency>
                                    <comp>n/a</comp>
                                </competency>
                                <link></link>
                           </resource>
                        </unitMaterial> 
                    </unit>
                </units>
            </course>
            <course>
                <courseInfo>
                    <department>IRLS</department>
                    <courseNumber>515</courseNumber>
                    <courseTitleInfo>
                        <courseTitle>Org ofInfo</courseTitle>
                    </courseTitleInfo>
                </courseInfo>
                <units>
                    <unit>
                        <unitInfo>
                            <unitNumber>1</unitNumber>
                            <unitTitle>Course Overview</unitTitle>
                        </unitInfo>
                        <unitMaterial>
                            <resource>
                                <type>book chapter</type>
                                <titleInfo>
                                    <title>Org of Recorded Inf</title>
                                </titleInfo>
                                <authorInfo>
                                    <author>
                                        <firstName>Arlene G.</firstName>
                                        <lastName>Taylor</lastName>
                                    </author>
                                    <author>
                                        <firstName>Daniel</firstName>
                                        <lastName>Joudrey</lastName>
                                    </author>
                                </authorInfo>
                                <dateInfo>
                                    <dateIssued>2008</dateIssued>
                                </dateInfo>
                                <extent>
                                    <pages>
                                        <numberPgs>33</numberPgs>
                                    </pages>
                                </extent>
                                <hostWork>
                                    <book>
                                        <titleInfo>
                                            <title>The Org ofInfo</title>
                                            <subTitle>3rd Ed</subTitle>
                                        </titleInfo>
                                        <author>
                                            <firstName>Arlene</firstName>
                                            <lastName>Taylor</lastName>
                                        </author>
                                        <originInfo>
                                            <publisher>LibUnl</publisher>
                                            <place>Westport, Conn</place>
                                        </originInfo>
                                    </book>
                                </hostWork>
                                    <competency>
                                        <comp>n/a</comp>
                                    </competency>
                            </resource>
                        </unitMaterial>
                    </unit>
                </units>
            </course>
        </courses>
    </semester>

    <semester>
        <semesterInfo>
            <semNumber>2</semNumber>
            <season>Summer</season>
            <semYear>2014</semYear>
        </semesterInfo>
        <courses>
            <course>
                <courseInfo>
                    <department>IRLS</department>
                    <courseNumber>540</courseNumber>
                    <courseTitleInfo>
                        <courseTitle>Intro to Archives</courseTitle>
                    </courseTitleInfo>
                </courseInfo>
                <units>
                <unit>
                    <unitInfo>
                        <unitNumber>1</unitNumber>
                        <unitTitle>History and Theory</unitTitle>
                    </unitInfo>
                    <unitMaterial>
                        <resource>
                            <type>book chapter</type>
                            <titleInfo>
                                <title>Metadata: Description</title>
                            </titleInfo>
                            <authorInfo>
                                <author>
                                    <firstName>Arlene G.</firstName>
                                    <lastName>Taylor</lastName>
                                </author>
                                <author>
                                    <firstName>Daniel N.</firstName>
                                    <lastName>Joudrey</lastName>
                                </author>
                            </authorInfo>
                            <dateInfo>
                                <dateIssued>2008</dateIssued>
                            </dateInfo>
                            <extent>
                                <pages>
                                    <numberPgs>45</numberPgs>
                                </pages>
                            </extent>
                            <hostWork>
                                <book>
                                    <titleInfo> 
                                        <title>The Org of Inf</title>
                                        <subTitle>Third Ed</subTitle>
                                    </titleInfo>
                                    <author>
                                        <firstName>Arlene</firstName>
                                        <lastName>Taylor</lastName>
                                    </author>
                                    <originInfo>
                                        <publisher>Lib Unl</publisher>
                                        <place>Westport, Conn</place>
                                    </originInfo>
                                </book>
                            </hostWork>   
                            <competency>
                                <comp>n/a</comp>
                            </competency>
                        </resource>
                    </unitMaterial>
                </unit>
            </units>
        </course>
    </courses>
    </semester>
</MLIS>
```

What I had up until Friday was an HTML page that showed each semester, within it each course, and within each course all the units, and within each unit all the texts (resources).  I used jQuery toggle() to show and hide at each level.

Now the page will only display the first semester.  The loop no longer picks up the second semester, and I do not know why.  I am really desperate to solve this problem.

Comment: There's almost nothing we can do without seeing a [mcve] of your code, and a more in depth description of what you're trying  to achieve.

Comment: Try to post something then you've done to help with the answers